# Redshift regexp_replace Non-English Standard characters

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift

In redshift, I'm trying to to regexp_replace strings like the following example to maintain apostrophes, spaces, alphanumeric, but remove non-english-standard characters like Â. Is this possible?

```
'He's interested in addressing the challenges ofÂ #energy & Â #climateÂ change'
```

to

```
'He's interested in addressing the challenges of energy climate change'
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `/[^\x00-\x7F]/g` for non-ASCII characters.